# Specific partial sum of even/odd binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have a following sum:

$S_g=\sum_{k=0}^g k\binom{4g+2}{2k}$

I can transform it into a different sum

$S_g=(2g+1)\sum_{k=1}^g\binom{4g+1}{2k-1}$

What is the closed form or what is the method to deal with any of above sums?

Comment: This is a question for MSE, not MO.

Comment: Most questions related to partial sums of binomials I have come across was in MO. After your comment I checked for differences between MO and MSE. 
The question here, is the problem from my research, so it fits (though the solution appeared simple).

Comment: @user64494 It is arguably not appropriate to answer a question that you feel does not belong, because by so doing you are reinforcing the idea that inappropriate questions will be answered anyway.

Comment: @Todd Trimble: I'd like to demonstrate Mathematica abilities in this field, no more and no less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Maple,
$$ S_g = \left( g + \frac12\right) \left(16^g - {4 g \choose 2g}\right) $$

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I managed to find the proof. Please feel free, to include it in your post. 

Using $\binom{4g+1}{2k-1}=\binom{4g}{2k-1}+\binom{4g}{2k-2}$:

$\sum_{k=1}^g \binom{4g+1}{2k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^g \binom{4g}{2k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{g-1} \binom{4g}{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2g-1} \binom{4g}{k}=\dfrac{1}{2}(2^{4g}-\binom{4g}{2g})$

Comment: See also [OEIS sequence A000346](https://oeis.org/A000346)

Comment: This is $ a(n) = 2^{2n+1} $- $ {2n+1}\choose {n+1}$. How is this sequence  related to the sum under consideration?

Comment: $S_g = (2 g+1) A000346(2 g-1)$.

Comment: Thank you. How is A000346 useful to the question under consideration? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The Mathematica command

```
Sum[k*Binomial[4 g + 2, 2 k], {k, 0, g}]//FullSimplify
```

performs
$$16^g g-\frac{\Gamma (4 g+3) \, _3F_2\left(2,1-g,\frac{3}{2}-g;g+\frac{5}{2},g+3;1\right)}{\Gamma (2 g-1) \Gamma (2 g+5)}.$$